# Newbie : Steps to create new KendoUI mobile application using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, kendo-ui

What are the Steps to create new KendoUI mobile application using Visual Studio 2008 ?
Looking for a sample application if any

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter what IDE you use. You can start with the tutorial [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/build-apps-with-kendo-ui-mobile).